# How to run a bash script by java multiple times in correct way?

Tags: java, multithreading, bash

Does not need say I'm new in JAVA.

I wrote a JAVA app that user can run a Script in Linux machine and can run it several times. (script needs time (10-20 minutes) to do its job).

The problem is when I run this script several times the application get very slow even froze for hour to do it's job.

I used multithreading for this task. But I think I put it in wrong place. How to fix this issue?

the code is to large and has several classes to put it here.I just put the relevant code.

```
public static String executeWithTrace(String command, JTextArea output) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", command};
    try {
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
            output.setText(output.getText()+"\n"+s);
            output.setCaretPosition(output.getText().length());
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
            output.setText(output.getText()+"\n"+s);
            output.setCaretPosition(output.getText().length());
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is the place the executeWithTrace method called:

```
public void runMethod(final String ip) {

    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    ruSTB1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            input.setText(ip);


            if (Shell.methodssh( "rm -rf /afile " ,input,output) == null) {

                password=passwordMethod();

                Bash.executeWithTrace("bashScript.sh",output);



                }

            else {
                output.setText("Error \n Check IP address ");
                thrSTB1.interrupt();
            }
            SwingUtilities
            .invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                // @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar
                            .setIndeterminate(false);
                }
            });

        }
    };
    thrSTB1 = new Thread(ruSTB1);
    thrSTB1.start();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `executeWithTrace` method reads all output from `stdout` and `stderr` sequentially (first `stdout` and then `stderr`).

The documentation of the `Process` class says:

> The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, or even deadlock.

So your implementation might block. `proc.getInputStream()` and `proc.getErrorStream()` must be read in parallel.

It might look like (probably you have to adapt the exception handling):

```
public static String executeWithTrace(String command, JTextArea output) {
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", command};
try {
    final Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();

    new Thread() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

          BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
          String s = null;

          while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(s);
              sb.append("\n");

              final fLine = s;
              // update the text area in the EDT
              SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                      output.setText(output.getText()+"\n"+fLine );
                      output.setCaretPosition(output.getText().length());
                      System.out.println(fLine);
                 }
              }
          }
      }
    }.start();


    new Thread() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                  InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
          while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(s);
              sb.append("\n");

              final fLine = s;
              // update the text area in the EDT
              SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     output.setText(output.getText()+"\n"+s);
                     output.setCaretPosition(output.getText().length());
                     System.out.println(s);
                 }
              }
          }
      }
    }.start();

    proc.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return e.getMessage();
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but it didn't work. GUI still freeze when I run executeWithTrace method.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess `executeWithTrace` is executed in the EDT so it must not block. That means that you have to remove the `proc.waitFor()`. But that also means that you cannot return the results of the process stored in the StringBuilder. Alltogether I think you have to convert the code above to use a `SwingWorker` that reads the from the process in the background and returns the output as result of the SwingWorker.